# Fused Location does not work when i turn GPS off , it does not work with Wifi or cellular data?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

Ive tried to disable GPS and try it on virtual device but also in a real device to see if im eable to make some location updates .

I still dont get any location updates with closed GPS , any idea why ?
In android docs wifi or cellular data must give me the position updates right ?

Here is my code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  StreamSubscription<Position>? positionStreamSubscription;
  late LocationSettings locationSettings;
  locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    forceLocationManager: false,
    intervalDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    //distanceFilter: 50,
  );
  Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings);

  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 20), (Timer timer) async {
    positionStreamSubscription?.cancel();

    try {
      positionStreamSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
              locationSettings:
                  AndroidSettings(intervalDuration: Duration(seconds: 1)))
          .listen((Position position) async {
        double geofenceLatitude = xxxxxx;
        double geofenceLongitude = xxxxx;
        double geofenceRadius = 60;

        double distance = await Geolocator.distanceBetween(
          position.latitude,
          position.longitude,
          geofenceLatitude,
          geofenceLongitude,
        );

        if (distance <= geofenceRadius) {
          print('Inside geofence 100');
          // positionStreamSubscription?.cancel();
          // await service.stopSelf();
        } else {
          print('Outside geofence 100');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: How are you disabling GPS?  You might not actually be doing that-  you might be disabling FINE_LOCATION, which would cause fusedLocation to fail because it's a fine location provider.

Comment: I try to turn off GPS entirely , Settings ->Location ->off ,                 

I have one more setting that says precise location , you mean that  ?
 
I have this ON but when i close the GPS this also turns off .

Comment: If you turn off location that way then no location will work-  not cellular, wifi, or GPS.  If you turn off precise location but leave location on, then cellular will work.  Maybe wifi.  GPS will not.    The point of the location setting is to protect a user's privacy completely.  The point of precise is to allow an app to get your general area, but not your specific location

Comment: If you want to try to get a non-GPS location with the precise off but location itself on, you likely have to lower the location accuracy from high to low.  It seems like you're specifying high here

Comment: If i have the gps on and disable the precise location it still works with low accuracy also , i've read the google android docs and somehow i understood that it works only with wifi or cellular data ,lol docs are kinda misleading. I just try somehow avoid to spam the user everytime and asking to turn on gps etc . 

The basic idea is to trigger a geofence when he exit/enter so i want to work also that in the background or in foreground in order to be more "trusted" as an app ,are there any other alternatives of how i do that ? Thanks for your time .

Comment: How big is the geofence?  The bigger it is, the more likely low accuracy is good enough.  Low accuracy is good to around 5-10m most of the time.  Network based accuracy is more variable, but good to a few dozen meters.  If your geofence area is in the 10s or meters, low accuracy is probably good enough.

Comment: I want to make it for like 5-10 meter radius but the minimum value in the specific package i use is 60 meters .(i dont mind it , it does the job done) 

The thing is if i cant take background location it has no point . User will close the gps anyway after he uses the app .

Comment: 5 meters is pushing what even GPS can give you under some circumstances.  If you're in a specific well known place, consider using bluetooth beacons, which can triangulate your position to that accuracy.  Background location on more modern Android requires additional permissions.